# console.log not executed in on('submit') if event.preventDefault() is not done

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-chrome

This is really strange:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
   console.log('submit > this=%o', this);
});
```

Will not show any console message when the form is submitted, but this:

```
 $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
   console.log('submit > this=%o', this);
   event.preventDefault();
 });
```

Will show it. Why is that? The code must get executed in any case, so that the `preventDefault` has any effect!

I have only tested in Chrome, and I would say this is a Chrome bug. Or am I missing sth here?

Comment: This might be a security feature, interesting.

Comment: activate the 'permanent'-option(preserve log) of the console. When you submit the form you leave the document and the console will be cleared by default

Comment: @Dr.Molle: oooops! It was driving me crazy, so much that I oversaw this little detail!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code actually works, the problem is that the console is being cleared immediately because the page was reloaded due to the form submission.

The code `event.preventDefault();` has prevented the form from being submitted. This is why the console is not cleared and you are able to see the text being logged.

Comment: You are right, of course! In retrospective that is very easy to understand, but as I was fighting seven other problems I got confused.

Answer (score 0):

Works as expected here :)

```js
$('form').on('submit',function(e){
console.log('hell',this)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="http://www.google.com" method="POST">
  Field:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What system are you using?

Comment: Linux, but does not matter. Take a look at the answer by Joey, that's the right explanation